# Render a Jinja template stored on an FTP server

Tags: python, flask, ftp, jinja2

I have some templates on an FTP server, and my app is running on another server.  Can I use `render_template` to render a template at an FTP link?

Comment: like this：

`render_template("ftp file link")`  

i try to find that maybe i can read the content of the ftp files, but i think it's not a good way.

i have read the document about render_template but seems no method can do this, it's there any way to solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, one can use `render_template()` function with the template files on another server. Create a [loader](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#loaders) that gets the remote template from the link. In this example, I use an HTTP server, but you can use an FTP server by changing the URL passed to the UrlLoader constructor.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from jinja2 import BaseLoader, TemplateNotFound
from urllib import urlopen
from urlparse import urljoin


class UrlLoader(BaseLoader):
    def __init__(self, url_prefix):
        self.url_prefix = url_prefix

    def get_source(self, environment, template):
        url = urljoin(self.url_prefix, template)
        try:
            t = urlopen(url)
            if t.getcode() is None or t.getcode() == 200:
                return t.read().decode('utf-8'), None, None
        except IOError:
            pass
        raise TemplateNotFound(template)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.jinja_loader = UrlLoader('http://localhost:8000/')


@app.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('hello.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: this way have some problems, sometimes it will be 404 error when my files and my urls are really existed, and i cant find what is wrong, it means it will raise template not found error. can you tell which direction i can find the way to solve this problem. many thanks.